How do I fix these drywall corners?
My handyman got sick and bailed halfway through a small drywall project. He put corner beads in, but the outside corners are pretty rough. Do I just sand these or do they need another layer of mud?



Thats pretty rough drywall work. That will take a lot of sanding, then maybe a skim coat after the sanding.
